# UITableView комментировать комментарий

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

У меня есть UITableView в которой содержатся комментарии к конкретному фильм, нужно реализовать что-то вроде комментировать комментарий, то есть, есть главный комментарий от "Пети" а "Владимир" может от комментировать комментарий "Пети". Как такое можно реализовать на под iOS, я просто что-то не много тупо представляю себе это, не много зная как устроена таблица.

Comment: Это не таблица (список), а дерево. Поищите реализации на гитхабе или https://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Comment: То ли я слепой, то ли я не могу найти, веду к тому, что искал, не нашёл, поэтому и решил написать сюда.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=tree

Comment: Просто добавьте дополнительную UITableViewCell, в чем проблема? верните из numberOfRowsInSection:(NSINteger)section comments.count + subcomments.count, все зависит от уровня вложенности комментариев, если уровень всего один - тогда задача не очень сложная

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, нужно правильно организовать хранение данных (комментариев). Комментарии, дискуссии - это деревья, в данном примере корень дерева - это кино, следовательно необходимо знать как принято реализовывать деревья. Обычно это массив ветвей (ветвь в контексте данной задачи это объект класса Comment). Чтобы организовать древовидную структуру из комментариев, каждый комментарий должен иметь атрибуты:

```
Comment * parent;
NSArray * childs;
```

то есть ссылку на родительский коммент и массив дочерних комментов. Думаю что не стоит объяснять разницу между родительским и дочерним комментами?

Во-вторых, нужно реализовать минимальный набор методов работы с деревом комментариев: линеаризация в связный список, вставка комментария в дерево (комментирование). Линеаризация в список нужна для того, чтобы преобразовать глубокую многоуровневую структуру дерева, в плоский одноуровневый список. Проще говоря, чтобы иметь один единственный массив, в котором в подходящем порядке будут выстроены все комментарии, например вот: коммент 1, коммент 1.1, коммент 1.1.1, коммент 1.2, коммент 2, коммент 2.1 и тд. Далее этот список можно использовать как источник данных для UITableView, каждая ячейка будет совпадать с соответствующим комментарием. Если мы просто пишем коммент к фильму, то просто вставляем его в массив наших комментов. Если мы комментируем чужой комментарий, то это может выглядеть так:

```
@interface Comment : NSobject
...
-(void)addComment:(NSString *)text;
...

@implementation Comment
-(void)addComment:(NSString *)text
{
    Comment * newComment = [[Comment alloc] initWithText:text];
    self.childs = [self.childs arrayByAddingObject:newComment];
}
```

После каждого добавления комментария необходимо заново провести линеаризацию всего дерева, чтобы новый комментарий встал на свое место (под самым последним комментарием в конкретной ветке комментариев). В общем это тема слишком объемная, но в своем ответе я постарался указать в какую сторону гуглить.